# CSS - How to place image between 2 section divs?

Tags: html, css

how would I go about placing an image vertically between 2 section divs so that I can accomplish the following:

1. Set the exact width in which the image overlaps the section. Example - I want 30% of the height of the image to be part of the top div and 70% of the height of the image to be on the bottom div
2. Have consistency on all screen sizes/browsers for the above goal

Here's an example to illustrate what I mean:
[image: place image between divs]

From what I've read and seen, a lot of people just set margin to be a negative pixel amount or use top/bottom and set a pixel amount but i dont think this is compatible across screen sizes

thanks a lot for the help, it means a lot

Comment: Post your code what u have tried this site is for troubleshooting problems

Comment: can you place your image directly in your question body or include some html you have tried?

Comment: heres the image https://postimg.org/image/opt5o4x3t/ .... for code i basically just used what i described...which is negative margins by a px amount, but that has different results for different screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 parents around the image element, one with `position:relative;` and another (nested div) with `position:absolute;`. then for `img` tag, apply `margin-top:-30%;` to place it at desired position.

To center the image: we set `left:50%` to inner div (parent of image) and set `margin-left:-50%;` for image as shown here:

```css
#div1 {background: #e0f0e0; padding: 1em;}
#div2 {background: #e0e0f0; padding: 1em;}

#divImg {position:relative; border:1px solid red; }

#divImg2 {position:absolute; border:1px solid blue; left:50% }

#divImg img { margin-left:-50%; margin-top:-30%; }
```

```html
<div id="div1">Section 1<br/>Contents of div1 ...<br/><br/>123<br/>456<br/></div>

<div id="divImg">
  <div id="divImg2">
    <img src="http://triptopersia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Iranian-Cheetah-2.jpg" style="width:150px" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  Section 2<br/>Contents of div2 ...<br/>
  <br/>
  ABCD<br/>EFGH<br/>
  123<br/>456<br/>
</div>
```

- The red line indicates border of first position:relative div (divImg)
- The blue line indicates border of second position:absolute div (divImg2)

The final position of `img` element is shifted relative to second div by `margin-left:-50%; margin-top:-30%;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this you can insert `image` in `div` having `id` `img`

```css
#div1{width:400px;height:100px;background:red;}
#div2{position:relative;width:400px;height:100px;background:yellow;z-index:1;}
#image{width:40px;height:40px;background:green;position:relative;
margin-left:180px;margin-top:-20px;margin-bottom:-20px;z-index:2}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**USING % FOR WIDTH**

```css
    #div1{position:relative;width:50%;height:100px;background:red;z-index:2;}
            #div2{position:relative;width:50%;height:100px;background:yellow;z-index:1;}
            #image{position:absolute;bottom:-20%;/* 2/3=66.6 */
              left:35%;z-index:4;
            width:30%;
            height:30%;background:green;
            }
```

```html
    <div id="div1">  <div id="image"></div></div>
           
            <div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: but this uses the `px` units for margins not the percentage units as asked!

Comment: @S.Serp Thanks I have upadated it :)

Comment: no, its not ok yet, it should set vertical position,  30% of image height be at top section and 70% at below section (see the picture i put in edited question). the percent margin will not work easily in your code..

Comment: i think its ok now